# how to create a public app that can be integrated inside shopify's stores admin?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

This is a general question I know. I read the documentation and I'm completely lost. I know how OAuth works and I know how to do basic access to the API. But my question is:

How to create a public app that users can install? How can the app be integrated with store's panel dashboard? Initially, I don't want my apps to listed, do I have to host my own app?

Answer (score 1):

There are two kinds of Shopify apps: public and private apps. Public apps are listed in Shopify's App Store, where it's only place store owners can install apps. Private apps are built for specific stores so they aren't necessary listed anywhere.

You do need to host your apps, your apps are basically web applications.

Shopify provides an Embedded App SDK which you can use to integrate your app smoothly inside store owners' Admin panel. If you also use [Shopify Polaris](https://polaris.shopify.com/) to build front-end with ReactJS then your apps' user interface is exactly same as Shopify's

I have created a sample Shopify app with NodeJS - [hello-shopify](https://github.com/Tiendq/hello-shopify) - it's easy to start if you are familiar with NodeJS.